# Button for Update Table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an update button for my Table Rows.
My **Add** button Open the Form Input Fields, My **Hide** button Hide it, The **Edit** Button edits the Table TR Fields.

The Submit Button Creates a new TR with the new text that I put in the Fields.
I want also an Update Button aside the Submit one. When I edit a TR Raw and put something else in them. When I press update to change that TR Text.

Help me to fix this.

Here is my current HTML/Jquery.js Script

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <title ></title >
  </head >
<body >
<form class="a" action="" method="post" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="nume" id="btd1" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="prenume" id="btd2" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="email" id="btd3" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="telefon" id="btd4" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="parola" id="btd5" value="" >
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form >
<table border="2" >
    <tr >
        <td >Vlad</td >
        <td >Andrei</td >
        <td >vTask</td >
        <td >Ceva</td >
        <td >Alceva</td >
        <td class="buttons">
            <button class="add" >Add</button >
            <button class="hide" >Hide</button >
            <button class="edit" >Edit</button >
        </td >
    </tr >
</table >

</body >
</html >
```

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        var valid = true,
            message = '';

        $('form input').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            if (!$this.val()) {
                var inputName = $this.attr('name');
                valid = false;
                message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
            }
        });

        if (!valid) {
            alert(message);
        } else {
            $('table').append('' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd1').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd2').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd3').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd4').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd5').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td class="buttons" style="vertical-align: top"><button class="add" >Add</button><button class="hide" >Hide</button><button class="edit">Edit</button></td >'+
                '</tr>' +
                '');
            for(var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
                $('#btd' + x ).val('');
            }
        }
    });

    $("body").on('click','.hide',function () {
        $("form").hide();
    });
    $("body").on('click','.add',function () {
        $("form").show();
    });

    $("body").on('click','.edit',function () {
        $("form").show();
        $.each($(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(".buttons")'), function (key, val) {
            $("form input[type=text]").eq(key).val($(val).text());
        })
    });

    $("#show").click(function () {
        //$("form").show();
        //$("#btd1").val("Vlad");
        //$("#btd2").val("Andrei");
        //$("#btd3").val("vTask");
        //  $("#btd4").val("Ceva");
        //$("#btd5").val("Alceva");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Check this code

Why dont you add other field for save and edit

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>


    <title ></title >
  </head >
<body >
<form class="a" action="" method="post" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="nume" id="btd1" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="prenume" id="btd2" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="email" id="btd3" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="telefon" id="btd4" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="parola" id="btd5" value="" >
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
  <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" style="display:none;" name="save" />
</form >
<table border="2" >
    <tr>
        <td >Vlad</td >
        <td >Andrei</td >
        <td >vTask</td >
        <td >Ceva</td >
        <td >Alceva</td >
        <td class="buttons">
            <button class="add">Add</button >
            <button class="hide">Hide</button >
        </td >
    </tr >
</table >

</body >
</html >
```

Javascript Code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".add").on("click",function(){
    $(".a").show();
  });
  $(".hide").on("click",function(){
    $(".a").hide();
  });
  $(document).on("click",".editEle",function(){
    row = $(this).parents("tr")
    var field1 = row.find("td:nth-child(1)").html();
    var field2 = row.find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
    var field3 = row.find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
    var field4 = row.find("td:nth-child(4)").html();
    var field5 = row.find("td:nth-child(5)").html();
    
    update(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5);

  });
  
  var update = function(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5){
    $("#btd1").val(field1);
    $("#btd2").val(field2);
    $("#btd3").val(field3);
    $("#btd4").val(field4);
    $("#btd5").val(field5);
    $("#submit").hide();
    $("#save").show();
  };
  
  $("#save").on("click",function(){
    var val1 = $("#btd1").val();
    var val2 = $("#btd2").val();
    var val3 = $("#btd3").val();
    var val4 = $("#btd4").val();
    var val5 = $("#btd5").val();
    row.find("td:nth-child(1)").html(val1);
    row.find("td:nth-child(2)").html(val2);
    row.find("td:nth-child(3)").html(val3);
    row.find("td:nth-child(4)").html(val4);
    row.find("td:nth-child(5)").html(val5);
    
  });
  
  
  $("#submit").on("click",function(){
    var val1 = $("#btd1").val();
    var val2 = $("#btd2").val();
    var val3 = $("#btd3").val();
    var val4 = $("#btd4").val();
    var val5 = $("#btd5").val();
    var ele = "<tr><td>"+val1+"</td><td>"+val2+"</td><td>"+val3+"</td><td>"+val4+"</td><td>"+val5+"</td><td><button class='editEle'>Edit</button></tr>";
    $("table").append(ele);
    
  });
  
  
  
});
```

Comment: Well Noushad Ali, what I want it to do now is when I press Edit on any raw. currently that raw is send up into the form input field boxes. I want to write something else there and then push an Update button to change the info in that TR. I'm bat at explaining .

Comment: In short, what I want it to do is write something today and maybe in 1 week the data in that TR will change and I have to edit it not add it at the bottom. So I need an Update button aside of the submit button

Comment: I want exactly what you did with the Edit + Update Button but the Edit button to throw the text into the form input fields like it does in my code and the save button that you did to save them

Comment: i think the above updated code is what your looking for

Comment: I don't want any of my buttons to disappear or alerts.